# Window.addEvent is not a function after merging js files

Tags: joomla, mootools

well i used joomla's ScriptMerge to merge all js files into one but now i get window.addEvent is not a function on squeeze box initialization,everything else is working fine except for this...i noticed that the squeeze box code is the only javascript block left in the head tag,all the other scripts are merged and moved to body...when i click a button that opens squeeze box it wont open of course,but when i click it again it opens normally...does anyone have an idea how to resolve this error?maybe it is because now the mootools core is being called in the merged js file but not in the head so the squeeze box code returns error because it doesnt have the mootools core?

Comment: Yes - this sounds like the problem - if the squeeze box script in the head and it tries to use `window.addEvent` it will throw an error - mootools libs should be the first thing loading - so or move all the  script from body to head or put squeeze box script after the body script

Comment: well i already tried moving the script with squeezebox from the head to the body and after the merged js file and it didnt change anything...

Comment: try to print `console.log(window.addEvent);` and see what you get. can you post a link ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is your problem: 
You are using **async** attribute on the script - **async** means the script will load and not holding the dom execution like the default behavior does(without **async** or **defer**).
so you try to call `window.addEvent` when you don't have **mootools** loaded to the page and this is why you get the error of `undefined`.

2 solutions for the problem:

1. remove the **async** attribute to force the script to hold until loaded and then continue executing the dom.
2. add to the script tag the `onload` event and execute the rest of your script there:

`<script src="http://tereni.me/cache/plg_scriptmerge/975e10ecd911c8ca09713d1120c51a6d.js" async type="text/javascript" onload="onLoadScript();"></script>`

and after it inside another script tag:

```
function onLoadScript(){
        window.addEvent('domready',function(){
            alert('dom is ready');
        });
    }
```

Comment: first solution worked for me,i cant believe i havent seen it myself...i spent hours debugging this!thanks man!

Comment: mootools was missing confirmed as well